# There is a plan to move servers from one data center to the other,SP 2013 Servers will be migrated with same domain and Host Name

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

There is a plan to move servers from one data center to the other,SP 2013 Servers will be migrated with same domain and Host Name
Can anyone suggest me what steps i have to taken care.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shutdown the servers and migrate them. That's all you need to do based on the information given to us. And provided you cannot have two machines with the same NetBIOS domain name in the same broadcast domain/Active Directory domain, it would be your only option.

Comment: We have 2 WFE,2 app nodes and 1 CA server, do we requeire to take farm backup?

Comment: You said you were moving data centers, so that would indicate you would not be restoring from a backup but rather just moving the physical machines or VMs. A backup prior to move doesn't hurt in case something catastrophic goes wrong during the move, but hopefully you won't have to use it.

Comment: Thank you for the response!! and 2. Database instance will be migrated with new servers with same Domain? for this what actions I have to taken care?please suggest me?

Comment: This article has the reference you need: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512725.aspx.

Comment: Sorry to asking question here. I have similar case on sp2010. We will shutdown and moving a WFE and an APP server. It takes 48 hours to move. During move the farm still active. Do we need to do anything like reset timer job cache?